# How to get contact name for incoming call

Tags: android

I am able to display the phone no of incoming call number using foll code

```
fname=intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
```

How to get the contact name ?

Comment: I've never tried it before, but I assume that after you get the phone number you need to search in the phone's contacts for the name using the number.

Comment: Yeah probably you should use Content Provider to query and get Contact name.

Comment: this link answers your question http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html